# copy a folder from git repository to remote server by ssh

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci-runner

I am attempting .gitlab-ci.yml of gitlab-runner.

In the project repository, there is a folder called "prod", and I would like to copy it to a remote server using ssh:-

```
- eval $(ssh-agent)
- ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_key.pem
- ssh -p22 root@remote_ip "some command to copy prod/* to /home/wwwroot/project/new_folder"
```

I have no idea on how the syntax be, could anyone suggest?

Comment: I think what you want is `scp`, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/686394/scp-between-two-remote-hosts-from-my-third-pc).

Comment: yes, you are correct! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Could you accept my answer as correct, if that works for you, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `scp`, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/686394/scp-between-two-remote-hosts-from-my-third-pc).

It basically allows you to transfer files between different machines. Apparently, gitlab ci supports scp.